# Stainless nonstick, not vs, but both? What's the point?

Tags: non-stick, stainless-steel, skillet

I bought a stainless steel 12" skillet and when it arrived it has a Non stick coating on the inside. I didn't realize that. I already have a non stick set, anodized aluminum I think, so I wanted to explore stainless. I'm seeing a lot of similar pans, from all the brands. What's the point of putting non stick in stainless? Is it just for style/looks or is there actually a benefit? Should I keep it and try it out? Or will I see the same results as my other non stick set?

Comment: It might be helpful to tell us the brand or to provide an Amazon link.

Comment: William Sonoma. Didn't think brand would matter. I'm just talking about the style of pan, nonstick stainless steel, regardless of brand. Why bother?

Comment: It gives us a place to start looking for *their* explanation for it. Thanks.

Comment: Because people with induction stoves want a non-stick pan :)

Comment: @setek: No they don't, not me in any case.

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt do you care to explain?

Comment: @setek: Why would I specifically want a non-stick pan with an induction stove?

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt erm, no, "**some people** with induction stoves want a non-stick pan." Happy?

Comment: @setek: Better, even better would be: *"some people want a non-stick pan"*. I don't see how induction has anything to do with it :)

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt it addresses why somebody would want a stainless steel pan with non-stick?

Comment: @setek: People with an electric or gas stove don't use non-stick pans? In other words: Where exactly and specifically does an induction stove fit in with the desire for a non-stick pan?

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt you're focussing on entirely the wrong part. I'm not saying people with other stoves don't want non-stick, I'm saying people with induction stoves, who are wanting a non-stick pan, cannot use aluminium non-stick pans, so would search for something that's stainless steel and non-stick.

Comment: @setek: Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaah. It's still early here (although there are other non-stick options besides stainless steel available for induction stoves) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many stainless steels are ferric, so will work with induction cooktops. Aluminum cannot interact with magnetism, so cannot work on induction, so many companies offer stainless steel non-stick pans for the induction market.

You won't see much difference in performance, and since it's not what you want in the first place I'd send it back unused.

Comment: Ah that makes sense then. Returning I will do! Thanks!

Comment: I thought I did. I was using the phone app.... that's weird.